# Building and deploying production build of Node.js TypeScript server

Tags: node.js, typescript, build, production, dev-to-production

I see many questions about how to deploy production build of Node.js app on server, but I not found any about building and deploying TypeScript server.

I am using GitHub Actions to build my TS into JS to /dist folder, but I realized that I can't just move this folder to server and start it.
I also still need to install dependencies, because it is not same as on Client-side (React for example) where all dependencies are bundled.

Are there any best practices how to automatically deploy those kinds of server apps?

Or it is simple as:

- Bulding TS to JS
- Moving /dist and package.json to production server
- Running script on server to `yarn install` and launch pm2

Comment: To ensure a good server deployment to prod, I would use a docker build as well, which can be tested together with all of its dependencies, then you can test that container, and not wonder if you remembers to put all dependencies and build correctly and your server actually runs

Comment: So I should build code, create docker, install production dependencies and then deploy docker to server?

Comment: Yes, once you have a ready docker, you can: test the production machine, scale easily, deploy without any build/installations/dependencies. Depending on the cloud you're using, all major clouds offer an OOTB deployment of docker web servers. You can follow the official docs here: https://nodejs.org/fr/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: Seems like docker is not very easy to setup without using Docker Hub and I have private repo already there. I want to use something like `pm2` deployment, but now I am trying to answer myself, if I should create GitHub branch where I will put just built source what will be installed to productioin server

Comment: I think this is a much safer approach. Good luck :)

Comment: Yes but is it really good to push built source to git?